# How to generic a optional parameter in Dart/Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, generics

I have a problem when I try to make some interfaces and need to implement them with a generic.
**My question is how can I use a nothing type like**

*Nothing in Kotlin*

*Void in Java*

**Example:**

I have a base class

```
abstract class Base<Out, In> {
  Future<Out> perform(In);
}
```

normal case I use, it perfect

```
class Download implements Base<bool, String> {

  @override
  Future<bool> perform(downloadUrl) async {
    // do download and return result here
  }
}
```

In some cases, I don't need to include any parameters.
but it require 2 generic type so I have to include void as input

```
class DoSomething implements Base<bool, void> {

  @override
  Future<bool> perform(_) async {
    // do some thing here, no use the input parameter
  }
}
```

The problem is when call perform function in DoSomething class it treat void as type of function don't like as Java, it require a input parameter instead of nothing

```
DoSomething().perform((){});
```

I don't want to include any parameter in the perform function.
Please give me any suggestions, solution to handle this case.

Comment: I found a solution, add a optional parameter use [] but it mean, all inherited classes will have to optional


abstract class Base<Out, In> {
  Future<Out> perform([In]);
}

Answer (score 2):

you can use

```
function({dynamic optional_parameter})
```

its an optional parameter you can simply ignore it if you dont want to process/use it and it will be null.

Comment: but with that I can't change the name of "optional_parameter" in inheriting classes

Comment: Does it have other options to use optional parameter and also can change the parameter name?

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same issue before, you could use the positional optional parameter in your override method

for example

```dart
class DoSomething implements Base<bool, void> {

  @override
  Future<bool> perform([_]) async {
    // do some thing here, no use the input parameter
  }
}
```

or u could simply make another Base without input

```dart
abstract class VoidBase<Out> {
  Future<Out> perform();
}
```

if you make the input is optional for the [perform] function, u will be forced to make it optional though for all implementation classes